# Failed to build the scheme no such module in Preview WatchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I am getting an error in the preview section for the watchOS application. But it works when I build it. I get the like following errors in Preview. How can I solve it?`no such module 'QuartzCore'

```
Compile RoundedCorners.swift (arm64):
/Users/msy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-gkorwbacqzvxvgcmrpdkaxfxnnmu/SourcePackages/checkouts/lottie-ios/Sources/Private/CoreAnimation/Animations/CAAnimation+TimingConfiguration.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'QuartzCore'
import QuartzCore
       ^

Compile Shape.swift (arm64):
/Users/msy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-gkorwbacqzvxvgcmrpdkaxfxnnmu/SourcePackages/checkouts/lottie-ios/Sources/Private/CoreAnimation/Animations/CAAnimation+TimingConfiguration.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'QuartzCore'

import QuartzCore
       ^ Compile LottieAnimationView.swift (arm64):
/Users/msy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-gkorwbacqzvxvgcmrpdkaxfxnnmu/SourcePackages/checkouts/lottie-ios/Sources/Private/CoreAnimation/Animations/CAAnimation+TimingConfiguration.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'QuartzCore'
import QuartzCore
       ^Copy FirebaseAnalyticsSwift.swiftmodule (arm64):
error: /Users/msy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-gkorwbacqzvxvgcmrpdkaxfxnnmu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/TestApp Mobil Watch App/Intermediates.noindex/Firebase.build/Debug-watchsimulator/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift.swiftmodule: No such file or directory (in target 'FirebaseAnalyticsSwift' from project 'Firebase')
`
```